# after pressing iconbutton in listTile in flutter all the iconbuttons are getting changed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

---

> **in following ListTile in trailing iconButton when i press the IconButton its changing the color of all icon buttons in listTile ...i
> want to change particular IconButton only**
> import 'package:comment_box/comment/comment.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:peta/api_storage/storage.dart';
>
> ```
> class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
>   final String? img;
>   const CommentPage(this.img, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>   //const CommentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   State<CommentPage> createState() => CommentPageState();
> }
>
> class CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {
>   Color _likeIcon = Colors.grey;
>   //final myposts mypost;
>
>   // bool toggle=false;
>   final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
>   final TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();
>
>   Widget commentChild(data) {
>     return ListView(
>       children: [
>         Image(
>           image: NetworkImage(widget.img.toString()),
>         ),
>         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
>           Padding(
>             padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 8.0, 2.0, 0.0),
>             child: ListTile(
>               isThreeLine: true,
>               //dense: true,
>               leading: GestureDetector(
>                 onTap: () async {
>                   // Display the image in large form.
>                   print("Comment Clicked");
>                 },
>                 child: Container(
>                   height: 50.0,
>                   width: 50.0,
>                   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
>                       color: Colors.blue,
>                       borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
>                   child: CircleAvatar(
>                       radius: 50,
>                       backgroundImage: CommentBox.commentImageParser(
>                           imageURLorPath: data[i]['pic'])),
>                 ),
>               ),
>               title: Text(
>                 data[i]['name'],
>                 style:
>                     TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
>               ),
>
>               subtitle: Column(
>                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
>                 children: [
>                   Text(
>                     data[i]['message'],
>                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
>                   ),
>                   SizedBox(
>                     height: 9,
>                   ),
>                   Row(
>                     children: [
>                       Text(data[i]['date'],
>                           style: TextStyle(
>                             fontSize: 12,
>                             color: Colors.grey,
>                             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                           )),
>                       SizedBox(
>                         width: 13,
>                       ),
>                       Text(
>                         data[i]['likes'],
>                         style: TextStyle(
>                           fontSize: 12,
>                           color: Colors.grey,
>                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       SizedBox(
>                         width: 13,
>                       ),
>                       Text(
>                         'Reply',
>                         style: TextStyle(
>                           fontSize: 12,
>                           color: Colors.grey,
>                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       SizedBox(
>                         width: 13,
>                       ),
>                       Text(
>                         'Send',
>                         style: TextStyle(
>                           fontSize: 12,
>                           color: Colors.grey,
>                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ],
>                   )
>                 ],
>               ),
>               `trailing: IconButton(
>                 color: _likeIcon,
>                 highlightColor: Colors.red,
>                 iconSize: 18,
>                icon: Icon(
>                   data[i]['icon']
>                   //Icons.favorite,
>                 ),
>                 onPressed: () {
>                   setState(() {
>                     //toggle=!toggle;
>                     //_likeIcon = data[i]['color'];
>                     _likeIcon == Colors.grey ? _likeIcon=Colors.red : _likeIcon=Colors.grey;
>                   });
>                 },
>               ),
>               // trailing: Text(data[i]['date'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,color: Colors.white)),
>             ),
>           ),
>       ],
>     );
>   }`
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: Text("Comment Page"),
>         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
>       ),
>       body: Container(
>         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
>         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
>         decoration: const BoxDecoration(
>             //color: Colors.transparent,
>             image: DecorationImage(
>                 image: AssetImage('assets/BG/PetaBG.png'),
>                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
>                 colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
>                   Color.fromARGB(120, 0, 0, 0),
>                   BlendMode.darken,
>                 ))),
>         child: CommentBox(
>
>           userImage: CommentBox.commentImageParser(
>               imageURLorPath: "assets/images/dog1.jpg"),
>           child: commentChild(postcomments),
>           labelText: 'Write a comment...',
>           errorText: 'Comment cannot be blank',
>           withBorder: false,
>
>           sendButtonMethod: () {
>             if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
>               print(commentController.text);
>               setState(() {
>                 var value = {
>                   'name': 'New User',
>                   'pic': 'assets/images/dog1.jpg',
>                   //'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjRHcaendrf6gU5fPIVd8GIl1OgblrMMvGUoCBj4g=s400',
>                   'message': commentController.text,
>                   'date': '1s',
>                   'likes': '',
>                 };
>                 postcomments.insert(0, value);
>               });
>               commentController.clear();
>               FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
>             } else {
>               print("Not validated");
>             }
>           },
>           formKey: formKey,
>           commentController: commentController,
>           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
>           textColor: Colors.white,
>           sendWidget: Text(
>             'Post',
>             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
>           ),
>
>           // Icon(Icons.send_sharp, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

---

Comment: Can you format your code bit nicer and share whole page?

Comment: Can you share your complete code so I can help you

Comment: its saying code is not formatted i am new to this so i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you mentioned here, you only have one color variable assigned to all the items in your list; if that variable changes, all items changes too.

But if you provide compete page code then I can help more in this.